# Proving an identity, cos and sin, two variables

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{\cos(2x)+\cos(2y)}{\sin(x)+\cos(y)} = 2\cos(y)-2\sin(x)$$

The question asks to prove the identity. I tried simplifying the first half, thought maybe I could expand and simplify with the double angle formulas.

Changed it to $$\cos(x)^2 - sin(x)^2 + cos(y)^2 - sin(y)^2$$ and tried a few thing like that, but I'm stuck at that point. Am I even on the right track here, or way off?

Comment: Try cross-multiplying with the denominator as a start.

Comment: That involves assuming it's an equality in the first place...

Comment: Try using the other identities for cos(2x) (and cos(2y)).

Comment: @Chappers Two ratios are equal *if and only if* the cross multiplications are equal.

Comment: @egreg I'm just cautious because I constantly see students start with $a=b$ and work down to $0=0$ at the end, rather than starting with something that is known to be mathematically coherent like $a-b$ and showing it's equal to zero, or $a/b$ and showing it's equal to $1$.

Comment: @Chappers, so what? If the expression would be false we would get a contradiction..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have, using the identity $\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}=1$:
$$ \cos{2x} = \cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x} = 2\cos^2{x}-1 = 1-2\sin^2{x}. $$
Then
$$ \cos{2x}+\cos{2y} =1-2\sin^2{x} + 2\cos^2{y}-1 = 2(\cos^2{y}-\sin^2{x}) \\
= 2(\cos{y}-\sin{x})(\cos{y}+\sin{x}), $$
and dividing gives the required identity.

Answer (score 0):

The two give expressions are equal if and only if $\sin x+\cos y\ne0$ and
$$
\cos2x+\cos2y=2(\sin x+\cos y)(\cos y-\sin x)
$$
The right hand side can be rewritten as
$$
2\cos^2y-2\sin^2x
$$
and we can recall the half-angle formulas
$$
\cos^2y=\frac{1+\cos2y}{2},\qquad
\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos2x}{2}
$$
so the right hand side becomes
$$
2\frac{1+\cos2y}{2}-2\frac{1-\cos2x}{2}
$$